# Is there a way to get all file URLs for a library with a single REST request?

Tags: 2013, rest, library, guid

I have a bunch of images in a library that I need to get URLs for each item. I can get the GUIDs with this:

```
/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Rotating%20Banner')/items
```

Is there a way to quickly get URLs for each item.

Answer (score 9):

At least three options are available:

**Option 1**

Retrieve File Url via projected `File` object:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items?$select=File/ServerRelativeUrl&$expand=File
```

**Option 2**

Retrieve File Url via `FileRef` property:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items?$select=FieldValuesAsText/FileRef&$expand=FieldValuesAsText
```

**Option 3**

Retrieve files using `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` endpoint:

```
/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<list url>')/Files?$select=ServerRelativeUrl
```

Comment: How do you know what to put for $expand?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming it's a Document Library, you can use $expand to bring information from the File along with the query

Should be something like this:

```
/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Rotating%20Banner')/items?$select=Id,Title,File/ServerRelativeUrl&$expand=File
```